# Sencha Touch: how do I play video NOT in full screen on iPhone?

Tags: youtube, sencha-touch-2, fullscreen

My question is as described by the title.

Here's the code.

```
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            id: 'msgList',
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(  
                '<div class="video youtube"><iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="240" height="160" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{string}" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>'      
            ),
            store: {
                fields: ['string']
        }
```

When the code runs on Safari, it works just fine as the video is played within. But on iPhone when I click on the video, it just go into fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the framework you're using is HTML based, it is not possible to play video in any way other than full-screen on iPhone.

Even if you were coding native, I believe it would still be a massive headache to do what you're asking; the iPhone video player is not designed to run embedded in other content.